# "Indirect proof" of a very simple metric space sequence limit problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I'm going through "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" Q7 for section 1.4 asks me to give an indirect proof for $$d(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow d(x, y)$$ if $x_n \rightarrow x$, $y_n \rightarrow y$, where $(x_n), (y_n), x, y$ are points in a metric space $X$. The "direct proof" in the book uses the triangular inequality $d(x_n, y_n) \le d(x_n, x) + d(x, y) + d(y_n, y)$, and this method is also the only one I can come up with, so what would be an "indirect proof"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "indirect proof" usually starts with "Suppose not." So to go about this, suppose $d(x_n,y_n)$ does not tend to $d(x,y)$ as $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to y$. Then there is an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that there exists no $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $$|d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y)| \geq \epsilon_0$$ Now use the triangle inequality as in the direct proof to get a contradiction.

Comment: Ah so it's just proof by contradiction?

Comment: Essentially that's what it means